# How do I make a vector/array of System::Windows::Forms::Checkbox^

Tags: windows, arrays, vector, checkbox, c++-cli

Couldn't find any answer to this problem, or not even any questions asked.
So what I'm trying to do, is a std::vector, maybe just a normal array, of Checkboxes.

```
std::vector< System::Windows::Forms::CheckBox^ >m_items;
m_items.push_back( myCheckbox );
```

That's what I currently have, and it clearly ain't working.
So does anyone have any ideas, on how to get it working, cause I've tried everything I can, but vectors don't seem to support Checkboxes.

Incase you need the error code:

```
c:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\VC\include\xmemory(200): error C3699: '&&' : cannot use this indirection on type 'System::Windows::Forms::CheckBox ^'
1>          c:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\VC\include\vector(421) : see reference to class template instantiation 'std::allocator<_Ty>' being compiled
1>          with
1>          [
1>              _Ty=System::Windows::Forms::CheckBox ^
1>          ]
1>          c:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\VC\include\vector(481) : see reference to class template instantiation 'std::_Vector_val<_Ty,_Alloc>' being compiled
1>          with
1>          [
1>              _Ty=System::Windows::Forms::CheckBox ^,
1>              _Alloc=std::allocator<System::Windows::Forms::CheckBox ^>
1>          ]
1>          d:\programming\vc++ projects\mahi wcs race maker\mahi wcs race maker\RestrictedItemsForm.h(69) : see reference to class template instantiation 'std::vector<_Ty>' being compiled
1>          with
1>          [
1>              _Ty=System::Windows::Forms::CheckBox ^
1>          ]
1>c:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\VC\include\vector(630): error C3699: '&&' : cannot use this indirection on type 'System::Windows::Forms::CheckBox ^'
1>c:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\VC\include\vector(655): error C3699: '&&' : cannot use this indirection on type 'System::Windows::Forms::CheckBox ^'
1>d:\programming\vc++ projects\mahi wcs race maker\mahi wcs race maker\RestrictedItemsForm.h(69): error C4368: cannot define 'm_items' as a member of managed 'MahiWCSRaceMaker::RestrictedItemsForm': mixed types are not supported
1>d:\programming\vc++ projects\mahi wcs race maker\mahi wcs race maker\RestrictedItemsForm.h(170): error C2663: 'std::vector<_Ty>::push_back' : 2 overloads have no legal conversion for 'this' pointer
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The regular `std::vector` does not support CLR reference types. Instead, you must use [`cliext::vector`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb386284.aspx). Include the following:

```
#include <cliext/vector>
```

And use with:

```
cliext::vector<System::Windows::Forms::CheckBox^> items;
items.push_back(myCheckBox);
```

Of course, you can also use the regular .Net collections, like [`List<T>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6sh2ey19.aspx), which behaves similarly as a `vector`.

Comment: Use List<>, not cliext: http://www.voidnish.com/Articles/ShowArticle.aspx?code=StlClrBclComparison

Comment: @HansPassant: Benchmarks that don't include a complete project aren't very helpful.  Benchmarks that don't even mention which compiler options were used are worse than useless.

Comment: Hmya, I know Nish pretty well.  Good man, I *know* he did it right.  It is obvious anyway, STL/CLR combines the worst feature of STL (value type behavior) with the worst feature of .NET (reference type behavior).  Take the three years to get it as a hint.  Nobody uses it.  Nobody should use it.  Nobody does.