# Error during template substitution reported by compiler

Tags: c++11, templates, visual-c++, c++-cli, sfinae

I'm seeing a build error which is correct, but something that I would expect to be ignored due to the Substitution Failure Is Not An Error rule:

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC\include\vector(895): error C3699: '&&': cannot use this indirection on type 'System::String ^'
RemoteWrapper.cpp(41): note: see reference to class template instantiation 'std::vector<System::String ^,std::allocator<_Ty>>' being compiled
        with
        [
            _Ty=System::String ^
        ]
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC\include\vector(918): error C3699: '&&': cannot use this indirection on type 'System::String ^'
```

Here's the code which the error mentions:

```
std::string nativeString;
String^ clrString = clr_cast<String^>(nativeString);
```

Here are the `clr_cast` templates:

```
template<typename TReturn, typename TSource>
TReturn clr_cast(TSource value)
{
    return (TReturn)value;
}

template<typename TReturn, typename TSource, typename = std::enable_if<!std::is_same<TReturn, TSource>>::value>
std::vector<TReturn> clr_cast(array<TSource>^ value)
{
    [iterate and cast]
}

template<typename T>
std::vector<T> clr_cast(array<T>^ value)
{
    [memcpy]
}

template<typename TReturn, typename TSource, typename = std::enable_if<!std::is_same<TReturn, TSource>>::value>
array<TReturn>^ clr_cast(std::vector<TSource> value)
{
    [iterate and cast]
}

template<typename T>
array<T>^ clr_cast(std::vector<T> value) // this is the problematic function
{
    [memcpy]
}

template<> std::string clr_cast(System::String^ value);
template<> System::String^ clr_cast(std::string value);
```

The compiler is trying to instantiate the function to which I added a comment and it's correct that it fails to do so. What I don't understand is that if I remove it then the compiler *will select the correct function* (the specialisation right at the end of the header) and continue happily onward.

It seems to me that the error I'm seeing is occurring during substitution, and that the compiler should therefore silently discard the `std::vector<T>` candidate and fall back on the specialisation. Why is this not happening?

Comment: clr_cast<String^>(name); not a c++11 code?

Comment: It's C++/CLI using C++11 features. `String^` in a .Net string.

Comment: i.e. you use managed and unmanaged code in there? if everything here is in managed section, I don't think that would relate to unmanaged (c++11). and this seem is caused by   `std::vector<>`, which does not support CLR reference type, have to use `cliext::vector`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I make a vector/array of System::Windows::Forms::Checkbox^](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7537809/how-do-i-make-a-vector-array-of-systemwindowsformscheckbox)

Comment: You misunderstand. I am not trying to convert to a vector at all: I am trying to invoke a method which casts from `std::string` to `System.String`. But the compiler is instead trying to invoke a method which casts from `std::vector<std::string>` to `System.String[]` and failing, when it should ignore the error and continue. Please remove the duplicate flag.

Comment: Well, it looks like that's your problem lies there. CLI compiler is known to breach SFINAE, there are known bugs  related to it. MS C++ native compiler also breaches  C++ standard  in few things, like ignoring conversion to avoid  ambiguity or substitution failures.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was happening because SFINAE only applies to the "immediate context", i.e. the template parameter itself.

The error can be turned into a substitution failure by moving the problematic instantiation into the template parameters, like this:

```
template<typename T, typename = T&&>
array<T>^ clr_cast(std::vector<T> value)
function
{
    [memcpy]
}
```

The code now compiles successfully, and the appropriate `clr_cast` overload is selected.